# How ROI coordinates in opencv works

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

How exactly coordinates in ROI works?
For example, I have image size of 450x280 (got it from opencv documentation). I want to select a ball. In documentation it says that `ball = img[280:340, 330:390]`, but that doesn't work for me, if I try `cv2.imshow("Image", ball)` I get this: `error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'`. So I tried to try different coordinates and it's totally confused me. After a lot of errors I came to this (`ball = img[235:275, 250:320]`). How exactly this numbers works? What is that grey zone to the right?
[image]

Original image

[image]

Result with coordinates [235:275, 250:320]

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Got it. Grey zone is just me being stupid. But the way coordinates works is kinda dumb.
So, our ball fits in square with coordinates 277:235 (top left) and 320:290 (bottom right). For some reason in opencv it looks like [235:290, 277:320]. Y's comes first
[image]

Comment: Row-major (also called C) ordering is one way of representing the items of an N-dimensional array in the 1-dimensional memory of a computer. This is the representation used by OpenCV [`Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details). In Python, a Numpy array is used to wrap the data efficiently, and thus shares the same ordering (which is [the default](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray) as well). Generally, it is good to be aware of how the datatypes you're using work. Documentation is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

In opencv you can do it like `[x:x1,y:y1]`,(for example: `[235:290, 277:320]`) where (x,y) is one coordinate and (x1,y1) is another.